# Best algorithm technique for checking two lists

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I have 2 lists:

1- A list containing users

2- A list containing work schedule

A work schedule contains

```
1st Entry (ex 09h00)
1st Exit (ex 13h00)
2nd Entry (ex 14h00)
2nd Exist (ex 18h00)
```

Each user has entry times to work, for example user A went to work and did the following

```
1st Entry (09h03)
1st Exit(12h58)
2nd Entry(14h03)
2nd Exit (17h51)
```

I am looking for an algorithm the go through all workers in list 1, and find the closest work schedule that fits each user.

For example, if 1st Entry, 1st Exit, 2nd Entry and 2nd Exit from schedule 1 is really close to user A, then it is a good approximation.

A naive implementation would be to go through each user and each work schedule but this is O(M*N) which i cant do, is there anyway to speed this up?

Comment: The usual solution is to tradeoff space for extra speed. Can you put one of the collections in a Map that would make the lookup `O(1)`?

Comment: Probably more accurate to say it's `O(M*N)` currently, since if either M or N are very small, saying it's N^2 is a bit misleading.

Comment: Thanks @user3483203 u are right. For some reason i wrote n^2

Comment: Do the work schedules follow a certain shape/structure? What is the reason stopping you from just going through the workers array and truncating to the nearest hour or half hour?

Comment: What is your definition of close? Is it the sum of the differences in entries/exit?

Comment: @JackLogan can you provide one more input example that has like atleast 5 entries. I feel combining binary search, we can do this in O(nlogm) time.